# How to load a function only once with JS or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I've been making some research these hours and without any success. I will explain my situation and I hope you help me in some way.

I'm making a project for my university, on my site I use the database on a local server with PHP my admin, PHP coding js functions, and `html/css`. My problem is that when I load the "dashboard site" I want to popup a modal from bootstrap which is a form to complete the second phase of registration, and that popup I do it with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('#exampleModal3').modal('show');
});  
</script>
```

I've tried to use `"include_once"` PHP function , or with JS use some tricks like: `if(!stuffdone){doSomething ... stuffdone=true;}`, but it's not working, when I load the dashboard the popup appears again and I cant make it show only once. My idea is to make it appear only once on the first login of the user and then it won't appear anymore and instead, it will be a button to change the user data which will call the modal popup. Also sorry for my English, is terrible.

Thank you

Comment: best option is to have column in database to know status of second phase registration. if set to 1 dont show pop-up if not show pop. after completion of second phase registration update column to 1.

Comment: Few notes:
* Please do not mix up php and jquery/javascript. One is executed at the server, the other in the browser. These are completely separate.
* include_once the 'once' works only for the current page that the user is reading, not for the next page the user loads.

Comment: * If you want the popup every session to return, use sassion_start() and $_SESSION['...'] variables. 
* If you want the popup to appear only once EVER, you need to store either a cookie or a database field like prasanna said.

Answer (score 0):

You could try localstorage to get the registration modal going. But you will have to store it in db and write a function in php that checks users registration progress. and keep in mind that localstorage is just clientside on that particular browser.  Something like this pseudocode:

```
var hasRegged = localstorage.getItem('hasreg');
function checkReg(){
    if (hasRegged===null){
        $('#exampleModal3').modal('show');
        localstorage.setItem('hasreg','1');
    }
}

$(window).on('load',function(){
    checkReg();
});  
$(document).on('click','.finishedregbutton', function(){
//Save the clickdata to db
});
```

you could also do this with ajax:

```
function checkReg(){
 $.ajax({
  "url":"regcheck.php",
  "data":"uuid=<?php echo $_SESSION['uuid'];?>",
  "type":"POST",
  "dataType":"JSON",
  "success": function(data){
     if(data.status=='completed'){
         $('#exampleModal3').modal('show');
     }
 });
}

$(window).on('load',function(){
    checkReg();
});
```